# jQuery AJAX call not returning results in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to build out a Load More button in my Wordpress app, but the AJAX return value is always 'success: false', even though I know there are more posts in the DB.  I followed a tutorial I found on YouTube, but not sure what I'm missing.

*JS*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  const button = document.getElementById('loadmore');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let current_page = document.querySelector('#main-content').dataset.page;
    // let max_pages = document.querySelector('#main-content').dataset.max;

    const params = {
      'action': 'load_more_posts',
      'current_page': current_page
    }

    $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', params, (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
})
```

*PHP (functions.php)*

```
wp_enqueue_script('loadmore', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/loadmore.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/js/loadmore.js'));

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts');
function load_more_posts() {
    $next_page = $_POST['current_page'] + 1;
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'paged' => $next_page
    ]);
    if ($query->has_posts()):
        ob_start();
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        get_template_parts('partials/blog','posts');
    endwhile;
    wp_send_json_success(ob_get_clean());
    else:
        wp_send_json_error('no more posts');
    endif;
}
```

The returned result continues to be:

```
data: "no more posts"
success: false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that usually gets me too, your ajax function should always end in a `wp_die();` function call, otherwise it will always return `0`, even if the rest of your code is correct.

In this instance:

```
function load_more_posts() {
    $next_page = $_POST['current_page'] + 1;
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'paged' => $next_page
    ]);
    if ($query->have_posts()):
        ob_start();
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            get_template_parts('partials/blog','posts');
        endwhile;
        wp_send_json_success(ob_get_clean());
    else:
        wp_send_json_error('no more posts');
    endif;

    wp_die();

}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried that, but I'm still getting the return of "data: 'no more posts', success: false".  Why would i get 'success: false'?

Comment: I was able to get the rest going, but this answer certainly got things started for me.  The other thing I was missing was, the method has_posts() should've been have_posts().

Answer (score 0):

Looks like u are passing wrong current page number, what there is in the let current_page = document.querySelector('#main-content').dataset.page; ??

Comment: Currently, the current_page variable is returning 1.

Comment: Are u sure u are asking for the correct post type? and that there is more than 12 post? If u try to set up the post per page in admin panel to 30 or so u see all the post ?